# How to ensure all HTML is loaded

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

how can I tell to JavaFX WebView to launch executeScript method only when all HTML, script files and CSS are loaded?

I've tried with:

```java
        we.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    loadTracks();
                    locus();
                }
            }
        });

        we.load(SERVER);
    }
```

There is a way to ensure all is loaded (especially Javascript) inside WebView?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaFX alert feature to check if the html has been loaded properly. Check this for more information [How can i get the data which has been generated using load html feature of JavaFx WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320938/how-can-i-get-the-data-which-has-been-generated-using-load-html-feature-of-javaf)